# How do i make a dictionary and use it to on a question thats being asked

Tags: python

import calendar

d=dict(enumerate(calendar.day_name))

d

{1:'Monday', 2:'Tuesday', 3:'Wednesday', 4:'Thursday', 5:'Friday', 6:'Saturday', 7,'Sunday'}

def question():
pew=str(input("Using 1-7 number as 1 is Monday and 7 Sunday, what day of the week is today?"))
print(d)
return

print(question)

Comment: Did you intend to comment some lines in your code ? it needs to be reformated.

Comment: Since I got you, I answered you. but please read this page : [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Second argument to the `enumerate` class is the start value. You need to set it to 1 here. Also `str()` is pointless because `input()` already returns a string.

```py
import calendar

d = dict(enumerate(calendar.day_name, 1))

def question():
    day = input(
        "Using 1-7 number as 1 is Monday and 7 Sunday,"
        " what day of the week is today? "
        )
    return d[int(day)]


print(question())
```